# Use regex to find a string starting from the beginning up to the first space in that string and replace it with what was found

Tags: regex

I have a long list of strings that are very similar in format.  Basically I would like to use regex to find the first part of the string (without empty spaces) and replace the string with what was found.  For Example using the string below the regex formual what return only `WN12-GE-000001` from:

```
WN12-GE-000001 - Systems must be maintained at a supported service pack level.
```

Comment: which language, which tool you're working with ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
^[^ ]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/0qitNi/4

Comment: On side note:- try string like `x - y - and` this regex will give you wrong result, because it doesn't consider start of string, also a lot simpler can `/^[^\s]+/`

Comment: @CodeManiac Hmm good call. I simplified the regex even further based on the `^` anchor. Hopefully there aren't other edge-case surprises withheld by OP